# Insert all the values in a row based on a selected checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have the following table that fetches data from the database:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo '
    <tr>
        <td width="320">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product_ID[]" value="'.$row['Product_ID'].'" />'.$row['Product_description'].'<br />
        </td>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="text" name="product_cost[]" value="'.$row['Product_Retail_cost'].'" maxlength="3" size="3" />
        </td>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="text" name="product_quantity[]" value="1" maxlength="3" size="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>';
}
```

What I would like to do, is insert the row into a table, making sure to insert any updated values from the two text boxes. The insert looks like this:

```
$product_ID = $_POST['product_ID'];
$product_cost = $_POST['product_cost'];
$product_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($product_ID);$i++)
    {
    $query="INSERT INTO mjj_ordered_products 
                (`Order_ID`, 
                `Product_ID`, 
                `Product_Quantity`, 
                `Product_Price`)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(Order_ID) AS Order_ID FROM `mjj_orders`),
                '".$product_ID[$i]."',
                '".$product_quantity[$i]."',
                '".$product_cost[$i]."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    }
```

But while this inserts the correct Product_ID, the remaining two values inserted do not correspond to the selected checkbox, but rather by looping through the entire list.

The question: how do I insert the other 2 values associated to the checkbox into the databse?

Comment: This may not help with your question, but `mysql_query` has been [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: Instead of writing queries by hand, and yours seem to have serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php), have you thought about using a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) to make this a lot easier?

Comment: @tadman I am using Netbeans. Should this not work as well as those mentioned by you (which I shall check out nonetheless)? And thanks for the reminder, before I publish this online I intend to address the SQL injection issues.

Comment: Netbeans is an editor, not a framework. A framework will provide a lot of PHP code for you that is a foundation to build off of instead of having to write every single thing from the ground up. If you look at frameworks like those you'll see you rarely have to write SQL by  hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Product_ID is unique, you can pass it as the index in all arrays like

```
<input type="text" name="product_cost['.$row['Product_ID'].']" value="'.$row['Product_Retail_cost'].'" maxlength="3" size="3" />
```

And then do something like

```
foreach($product_ID as $id)
{
  $query="INSERT INTO mjj_ordered_products 
                (`Order_ID`, 
                `Product_ID`, 
                `Product_Quantity`, 
                `Product_Price`)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(Order_ID) AS Order_ID FROM `mjj_orders`),
                '".$product_ID[$id]."',
                '".$product_quantity[$id]."',
                '".$product_cost[$id]."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. The problem is that the Order_ID is only created after the products have been selected. As a result, I cannot create the checkbox names with the Order_ID.

Comment: Oops, meant the Product_ID (you are using it already as the value for the checkbox), answer updated

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. It either doesn't complete the insert, or it behaves in the same fashion.

Comment: what does `echo $query` give you?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, where would I place that?

Comment: Generally, if a query fails or doesn't do, what you want it to do, it is a good idea to see what the query actually looks like. You can echo it right before the `mysql_query()` for example

Comment: To answer your question, I get this: `$query$query`. But I have retried your solution, and it seems to be working now!